# python script to run a node application and to output dependencies

Tags: python, node.js, github

I am trying to write a python script that will download a Node GitHub repository. once downloaded it will use build command to build the app, and then also to output the dependencies of this node project.

```
import json
import pymongo
import requests
import os
import subprocess
from git import Repo

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db = client['ibm_test']
collection_dep = db['dep']


headers = {'Authorization': 'token '}
r = requests.get('https://github.com/app.git', headers=headers)
#if(r.ok):
#    repoItem = package.json.loads(r.text or r.content)
#if  repoItem['language'] == 'JavaScript':

HTTPS_REMOTE_URL = 'https//git.url'
DEST_NAME = 'build/npm'
cloned_repo = Repo.clone_from(HTTPS_REMOTE_URL, DEST_NAME)
buildCommand = "build/npm/express-ibm/npm run-script devstart -b build/npm/express-ibm/package.json"
process = subprocess.Popen(buildCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output)
print(error)
    # depo = subprocess.run(cmd)
     #depo = subprocess.check_output(['ls','-l'])
     #depo = os.system("gradle dependencies")
    # depo = os.system('path gradle *./graldew dependencies*')
    # collection_dep.insert(depo)
f= open("npm.json","w+")
#print(depo)
print("end")
client.close()
```

**EDIT:** add exception trace back.

Original exception was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "node.py", line 34, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen(buildCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in init
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build/npm/express-ibm/npm'
```

Comment: any ideas, or documentation to help would be great , thanks

Comment: What happens when you run this code? do you get errors? please provide more details about what is not working so that others can assist you, at the moment it is not clear what your actual problem is.

Comment: riginal exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "node.py", line 34, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen(buildCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build/npm/express-ibm/npm': 'build/npm/express-ibm/npm'

Comment: This is the error i get. It s to do with the build command. The repo downloads to build/npm as if i go to the location i can run it from this location.

Answer (score 0):

The path 'build/npm/express-ibm/npm' does not exist.

You need to give a full path

```
exe_path = os.path.join('/the/path/to', 'build/npm/express-ibm/npm')
```

And use it in `subprocess.Popen` (or `subprocess.run` which is better)